# Remove math symbols from Vim

Tags: vim

My LaTeX code in Vim displays math symbols like integrals, exponents etc. just like in regular math notation. It also hides other symbols like dollar sign in inline math mode, or \left( is displayed just as (. Text is shown normally if the cursor is on that line. How can I disable this?

Comment: I am not familiar with LaTeX or what plugin you maybe using. What are you using? It is probably using `conceal`. See `:h 'conceallevel` and/or this plugin's help documentation.

Comment: Yeah, thanks. It was conceallevel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting conceallevel to 0 causes text to be displayed normally.
`set conceallevel=0`